# What is the best way to implement translation for a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script that will need to be available in 2 languages. To make my life easier, it seems like a good idea to me to create a language file for each, and include the strings in there, rather than having the text directly in the code and maintaining 2 copies of the code. Is there a best practice on how to implement this?

The roadblock that I'm at right now is that some of the strings will need to contain variables, so I've already run into some trouble there. I've noticed that it will use the value of the variable at the time that the string is set, which makes sense to me.

So for example, if I have a string which outputs an error level:

```
$Strings.ErrorMessage = "Error detected with $Level severity"
```

And then later set `$Level` to to whatever value, it won't have that value when the script is called. Assuming that `$Level` isn't set before setting `$Strings.ErrorMessage`, The output would look like:

```
Error detected at  severity
```

Is there a way to tell PowerShell to grab the current value of the $Level variable before it is output?

Comment: `$Strings.ErrorMessage = 'Error detected with $Level severity'` and `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Strings.ErrorMessage)` or `$Strings.ErrorMessage = 'Error detected with {0} severity'` and `$Strings.ErrorMessage -f $Level`.

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_internationalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link on [about_Script_Internationalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_internationalization) and [this link](http://www.plattsoft.net/2015/08/24/internationalization-with-import-localizeddata/) that goes gives an example:

**PSUICultureExample.ps1** *before localistion*

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
    "This is a small example showing how to localize strings in a PowerShell script.",
    "Hello, World!") | Out-Null
```

Code to create two localised scripts.

**Localized\PSUICultureExample.psd1**

```
ConvertFrom-StringData @"
MessageTitle = Hello, World!
MessageBody = This is a small example showing how to localize strings in a PowerShell script.
OtherMessage = Hello {0}!
"@
```

**Localized\es-ES\PSUICulture.psd1**

```
ConvertFrom-StringData @"
MessageTitle = ¡Hola mundo!
MessageBody = Este es un pequeño ejemplo que muestra cómo localizar cadenas en un script de PowerShell.
OtherMessage = ¡Hola {0}!
"@
```

**PSUICultureExample.ps1** *AFTER localistion*

```
$s = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath Localized)
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($s.MessageBody, $s.MessageTitle) | Out-Null
```

Then to include values within your strings (interpolation), you'd do something like this:

```
$ValueToInsert = 'Bob'
$s.OtherMessage -f $ValueToInsert
```

***Edit***
*Folders `Localized` & `Localized\es-ES` are relative to the script.*

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much! The only hiccup I had was when I typed `=f` instead of `-f`. I was wondering why it wasn't working, and why my hyphen was so blurry, but I figured I was just getting old ;)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to best practices, PowerShell's own help system has a page about that:

```
Get-Help about_Script_Internationalization
```

To avoid running into problems with expanding variables in localised strings, you can use the format string operator instead:

```
'Error detected with {0} severity' -f $Level
```